# How can I sort an array of objects from an API before passing them into a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

Hello I'm fairly new to react/js and I am trying to sort some data that I am fetching from the an api using Apollo then render the data into a grid. When I try to use the sort() function I get and error in the console "TypeError: Attempting to change configurable attribute of unconfigurable property.". Can anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks

This is the code I've tried. It works without the data.ammo.sort method.

I was expecting the data to be rendered in order sorted by damage

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import AmmoBox from "./components/Ammo"
import {Grid} from "@chakra-ui/react"

export const GET_AMMO = gql
`{
    ammo{
        item {
            id
            name
            shortName
        }
        damage
        penetrationPower
        caliber
    }
}`

function App() {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_AMMO);

  if (loading) return 'Loading';
  if (error) return 'Error';

  console.log(data.ammo);

  //sort data here before mapping to AmmoBox component*
  data.ammo.sort((a, b) => a.damage - b.damage);

  return (
    <Grid templateColumns='repeat(5, 1fr)' gap={6}>
      {data.ammo
      .map((ammos) => (
        <AmmoBox name={ammos.item.name} caliber={ammos.caliber} penetration={ammos.penetrationPower} damage={ammos.damage}/>))}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error says you can't change `data.ammo`, spread the data to a new (shallow-copied) array `sortedArray` and apply `.sort()` method to this new array.

Check code below:

```
function App() {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_AMMO);

  if (loading) return 'Loading';
  if (error) return 'Error';

  console.log(data.ammo);

  // Spread ammo data to a new shallow-copied array and use sort() function on the new array
  const sortedArray = [...data.ammo].sort((a, b) => a.damage - b.damage);

  return (
    <Grid templateColumns='repeat(5, 1fr)' gap={6}>
      {sortedArray
      .map((ammos) => (
        <AmmoBox name={ammos.item.name} caliber={ammos.caliber} penetration={ammos.penetrationPower} damage={ammos.damage}/>))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[Mozilla Docs - Array.prototype.sort() :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The sort() method returns a reference to the original array, so mutating the returned array will mutate the original array as well.
>
> In case you want sort() to not mutate the original array, but return a shallow-copied array like other array methods (e.g. map()) do, you can do a shallow copy before calling sort(), using the spread syntax or Array.from().

Comment: Thank You! I did try to copy the sorted results into a new variable at one point but I forgot to write data.ammo as [...data.ammo]. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can also use useMemo [to reduce renders](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state) and [cache results](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#caching-expensive-calculations)

```
function App() {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_AMMO);

  if (loading) return 'Loading';
  if (error) return 'Error';

  console.log(data.ammo);

  const sortedData = useMemo(() => {
       const copied = [...data?.ammo ?? [] ]
       return copied.sort((a, b) => a.damage - b.damage)
  }, [])


  return (
    <Grid templateColumns='repeat(5, 1fr)' gap={6}>
      {sortedData
      .map((ammos) => (
        <AmmoBox name={ammos.item.name} caliber={ammos.caliber} penetration={ammos.penetrationPower} damage={ammos.damage}/>))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to read up on useMemo a bit